# Lucene Combine FacetCollector and CustomTopDocsCollector

Tags: java, lucene

I already use lucene search (4.9) with Facet search/facet collector to print the Search Count for different categories.

Now I have to use a custom Collector (extends TopDocsCollector) to limit/filter duplicate entries from search result (if specific fields are filled with the same value, only one of this items should be returned as search result). This also works fine already.

I do want to display the result-count from the combination of the facet and the custom Collector in Combination.

E.g. if there are 5 documents with category A and 3 of them are "the same" (customCollector) then my result contains 3 Documents and Facet Count for Category A is "5" instead of "3".

```
Collector collector = null;
// wrap TopDocsCollector and FacetsCollector to one MultiCollector
collector = MultiCollector.wrap(customCollector, facetsCollector);
```

Is there another way to display the correct result count for this setup (facet filtered by Collector)?